# Program works for one true case, but not for other

Tags: c++

So, I wrote this program to check if a given number is an armstrong number or not. But when I ran this code with 153 as input (an armstrong) it shows "not armstrong", but when I ran it for other numbers like 370, 371 (armstrong numbers) it shows "Armstrong". Even more, when I ran it with an online compiler, it ran completely fine but on my laptop (using MinGW) it shows the error with 153. Here is the code (I have included the math.h file):

int n;
cin>>n;

```
int sum=0;
int originaln=n;
while(n>0){
    int lastdigit=n%10;
    sum+= pow(lastdigit,3);
    n=n/10;
}
if(sum==originaln){
    cout<<"Armstrong"<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"Not Armstrong"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

Also, can someone tell why this code doesn't work for 4 digit numbers?

Comment: Note: `pow()` is floating point. You might not want to do that when expecting nice, neat integers. Just use `x*x*x` for cubing.

Comment: Thank You, I have tried your approach and it works fine. But the thing is, the above mentioned code works fine in the video I watched, but doesn't on my system. And it also works fine with online compilers. What I want to know is why it doesn't on my system.

Comment: That's because [floating point behaviour](https://floating-point-gui.de) can be surprising. Not every CPU behaves identically. The real problem is that while 1.99999... is considered to be *effectively* 2.0, when converting to an `int` it's considered `1`. The tiny jitter is massively amplified for small numbers. Don't use floating point math for integer answers. Use it *only* when you understand the risks and compromises made.

Comment: @LakshayMalik for future reference, when dealing with problems solely related to *integer* calculations, introducing *any* of the floating point functions in an automatic code smell. Therefore, I suggest you take that into consideration when evaluating whatever 'video' you watched. If they either don't know this, or worse, know this and choose to ignore it, perhaps an alternative education source is in your best interest.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank You, I'll keep that in mind. And I'm pretty sure they know about this (she works at Microsoft) but chose to ignore it.

Comment: @LakshayMalik Even working at Microsoft is not a guarantee of knowledge about C++. I haven't seen the video you are referring to but if they are recommending using `pow` for integer exponents then they really do not know what they are talking about (at least as far as C++ goes).

Comment: @john So, I would have linked the video, but you won't understand it. What they basically did was, when they reached the cubing part, she simply said that we have a function to find out cube, `pow`, just make sure to include `math.h` in your header file if using `pow`.  And then proceeded to write `pow(lastdigit,3)`.

Comment: @LakshayMalik, well that just shows a lack of understanding, see all the comments above. SImply `lastdigit*lastdigit*lastdigit` should be preferred.

Comment: @john @WhozCraig So what I'm taking away from this thread is to never ever use `float point` when you for sure know that both input and output will be in integers. (Can you please give just a tad bit more explanation as to why, or a reading source) Does this also apply to any other data type? And are there any reading sources for other little things like this, like where to learn about these, I'm pretty sure experience is not the only way.

Comment: @LakshayMalik Here's a [basic guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) with links to more in depth stuff

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work for 4 digits because while updating the "sum" you are not taking care of the number of digits in the number

For example for a 4-digit number it should be:

```
 sum+= pow(lastdigit,4);
```

In order to create a standard approach, you can check for the number of digits in the number and then update the value for 'n' digits in a number

You can refer to this website for the approach: [Source](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/check-armstrong-number)

Coming to the test case for number: 153, the code works fine and provides the correct output

Check if you have correctly included the header file

You can run your code through an online compiler and check for yourself: [Source](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, it works fine with online compilers, but not on my laptop. And it works fine if instead of pow() I use x*x*x for cubing.